# По сочетанию клавиш вставить текст из div

Tags: javascript, textarea

```
//Событие на ctrl+space
txt = document.querySelector('textarea#txt');
txt.onkeydown = function(event){
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.which == 32){
    found = somediv.childNodes[0]
    .innerText
    .match(/\.(.+)$/);
    txt.innerHTML = found[1].trim()
}
```

Если сделать, как написано в коде, то это работает ровно один раз (после того, как текст уже оказался в textarea и нужно, скажем, удалить пару символов, применение ctrl+space перестает работать).

Если концовку сделать не `txt.innerHTML = found[1].trim()`, а `txt.value = found[1].trim()` то больше ничего нельзя дописать или удалить. А надо неоднократно использовать это сочетание клавиш и периодически редактировать вставленный текст. В чем тут дело?

P.s `somediv.childNodes` - множество `<p>Какой-то текст...</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для textarea вместо innerHTML нужно использовать value. Иначе действительно 1 раз работает и перестаёт.

Мой пример. Не понял зачем вам trim и match.

```js
txt = document.querySelector('textarea#txt');
txt.onkeydown = function(event){
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.which == 32){
    alert(document.getElementById("somediv").innerText);
       document.querySelector('textarea#txt').value = document.getElementById("somediv").innerText;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="somediv"><p>Какой то текст...</p></div>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

Comment: Насчет match и trim. Там после последней точки стоит номер телефона или два номера телефона. Таким образом, сочетание клавиш вставляет нам номер телефона (или два) в textarea.

Comment: Не знаю, что это вчера было. Когда я дела через value, как вы написали, невозможно было ничего дописать или удалить из текста. Будто я написал `txt.oninput = function(){ txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^\d]/, ''); }`. Спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> txt.innerHTML = found[1].trim()
> ```

```
txt.value = found[1].trim()
```

Comment: проблема глубже, у автора эти строки есть в вопросе =)

Comment: `Если концовку сделать не txt.innerHTML = found[1].trim(), а txt.value = found[1].trim() то больше ничего нельзя дописать или удалить`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не может так работать при коде из вопроса. Там же if выполняется только если  нажст Ctrl+Пробел.

Comment: да, так не должно быть, по этому и странно